# Make server don't stop listening socket connections

Tags: java, sockets

I am creating a socket server and client in Java.

My objective is that the server is always listening for connections and keeps them all at the same time.

The problem is that the server stops after listening to one socket connection.

Server Code

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package pkg1;

import java.io.*;

import java.net.*;

class Servidor {

    static final int PUERTO = 5007;

    public Servidor() {

        try {

            int numCli = 0;
            ServerSocket skServidor = new ServerSocket(PUERTO);

            System.out.println("Escucho el puerto " + PUERTO);

            for (;;) {
                Socket skCliente = skServidor.accept(); // Crea objeto

                numCli++;

                InputStream is = skCliente.getInputStream();
                byte[] mensaje = new byte[25];
                is.read(mensaje);
                System.out.println(new String(mensaje));

                 
                    if (new String(mensaje).equals("KEY007
```

Client Socket

```
package pkg1;
import java.io.*;


import java.net.*;


class Cliente {


  static final String HOST = "localhost";


  static final int PUERTO=5007;


  public Cliente( ) {


    try{


      Socket skCliente = new Socket( HOST , PUERTO );


      
      
    

        OutputStream os = skCliente.getOutputStream();
        String key ="KEY007";
        os.write(key.getBytes());
        
        InputStream is = skCliente.getInputStream();

        
        
                byte[] mensaje = new byte[25];

    is.read(mensaje);
    
        System.out.println(new String(mensaje));


      skCliente.close();


    } catch( Exception e ) {


      System.out.println( e.getMessage() );


    }


  }


  public static void main( String[] arg ) {


    new Cliente();


  }


}
```

Right now this code works and it connects between the two, but after the server gets one connection the server activity stops.

How can I make the server listen to all the socket connections and keep them all at the same time?

Many thanks for the help, I have been trying for days.

Comment: Generally, the server creates a Thread for each client.  In addition, the server listens in a timed loop for new connections.  Here's an example of a [Java server](https://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/java-socket-server-examples-tcp-ip).

Comment: Also well described here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html including a working example of s server accepting multiple clients.